# How to use gitignore with asterisks?

Tags: gitignore

I have a directory for IntelliJ I would like to leave out of my repo (the 'out' folder).

I tried to add this to my git ignore file:

```
*/out/*
```

I tried all sorts of variants of this. None of them work without filling out the entire exact path to the directory. So this is working:

```
someDir/AnotherDir/AnotherAnotherDir/out/
```

How do I use gitignore with asterisks?

Comment: just fix the path issue by opening the terminal in that folder and adding the path.

Comment: Turns out not using asterisks at all worked best for my case, as described in the answer.